# map function on mutli-dimension array

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have a large 4D array (time,height,latitude,longitude) of float values.  I want to efficiently force any values in the array that are greater than 100.0 to be 100.0.  I think the `map` function (+`lambda`?) can do this, but I'm stuck.  Currently I have a crude for loop that goes through each index, but this is taking much too long!

Thanks for your help in advance!

Solution: numpy.clip(array,0,100.0)

Comment: It will be helpful if you show what you have now.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if you are using ``map()`` and need ``lambda``, stop and use a generator expression or a list comprehension. It's faster and more readable.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be efficient, you should probably be using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/).

With NumPy you can have space efficient [multidimiensional arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) and ready to use [solution to your problem](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html#numpy.clip).

Answer (score 2):

> I have a **large 4D array** (time,height,latitude,longitude) of float values. I want to **efficiently**

stop.

Use [numpy](https://numpy.org/).